# Log4Net передать лог по почте

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

В общем, хочу скинуть лог по почте, когда программа будет на финальной стадии завершения.

Проблема в том, что когда я передаю лог, то в нем может не оказаться последних N сообщений. Вероятнее всего Log4Net буферизирует перед записью.

Как я могу насильно заставить его записать все из буфера?

Comment: Логи почтой это очень плохой тон сам по себе, найдите другое решение. Веб интерфейс для логов например..

Comment: @NewView, мб да. Но это самый простой вариант в моем случае.

Comment: Самый простой путь, это складывать их на диск :) настройке какой нибудь веб на эту папку, и всех дел. А по сути, откройте сайт Log4Net, там есть примеры.

Comment: Просто программа выполняется по расписанию планировщика и я бы хотел получать логи об успешности.

Comment: flush нужно выполнить. а вот как конкретно - не подскажу, с log4net не работал давно

Comment: Пробовал, что-то не помогло=(